# using tree node class in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a tree node and the tree node can be checked. The thing is that I need to be able to gray out or disable a specific node programmatically. So for instance

```
  [] Head Node
      [sub Node]
      [sub Node]
  [] another node 1
  [] another node 2
```

So lets say that I check "another node 2" then it should not dissapear but instead appear grayed out or disabled but still visible

so it would look like this

```
  [] Head Node
      [sub Node]
      [sub Node]
  [] another node 1
  [X] another node 2  //and this would be disabled but still visible
```

I hope you understand what I want to do just not sure how to disable it and still keep it visible.

Thank you

Comment: Are these tree nodes of some specific TreeView component? WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, something you just coded?

Comment: I specified asp.net and C#. Using the TreeView class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to "disable" an ASP.NET tree node. What you can do is disable its [select action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.selectaction.aspx), and [change its style](http://blog.dreamlabsolutions.com/post/2008/10/09/Styling-a-TreeNode-with-CssClass.aspx).